# why firebase data is not display on screen by using flatlist in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

but when i display data by using console.log it display properly
import React,{useState,useEffect,Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,View,Text,TextInput,TouchableOpacity, Button, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
import {fire} from '../config/fire';
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
function Donorlist(){
const[Donors,setDonors]=useState([]);
const fetchDonors=async()=>{
const response=fire.firebase_.firestore().collection('Donors');
const data=await response.get();
data.docs.forEach(item=>{
setDonors([...Donors,item.data()]);
//console.log("hI I AM IN DONORS FETCH LIST");
})

```
}
useEffect(()=>{
    fetchDonors();
    
},[])
return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
      data={Donors}
      renderItem={({item})=>(
        console.log(item.name),
        <Text>
        {item.name}
      </Text>      )}/>

            
      {
             
            
           /*
             Donors.map((Donor,index)=>{
          return(
               console.log(Donor),
            <View className="blog-container">
             <Text>Donor List</Text>
             
            <DataTable>
<DataTable.Header>
      <DataTable.Title
      style={{
        width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
      }} >Name</DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title
      style={{
        width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
      }}  >Email</DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title
      style={{
        width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
      }}  >Phone</DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title
      style={{
        width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
      }}  >Country</DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title 
      style={{
        width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
      }} >State</DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title >City</DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title 
      style={{
        width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'
      }} >Pin</DataTable.Title>     
    </DataTable.Header>
     <DataTable.Row>
    <DataTable.Cell ><Text>{Donor.name}</Text></DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell >{Donor.email}</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell >{Donor.phone}</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell >{Donor.name}</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell >{Donor.email}</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell >{Donor.phone}</DataTable.Cell>
      <DataTable.Cell >{Donor.phone}</DataTable.Cell>

      
     </DataTable.Row> 
    
    <DataTable.Pagination
      page={1}
      numberOfPages={3}

      onPageChange={page => {
        console.log(page);
      }}
      label="1-2 of 6"
    />


</DataTable>
<View>
  <Text>List Data</Text>
<Text>{Donors.name}</Text>
  </View>

</View>
      
      )
        })*/
      }
      

    </View>
  );
}
export default Donorlist;
```

Comment: Add `extraData={Donors}` props in your Flatlist and then check.

Comment: i Did this but no use

Comment: when i print data on console screen by using console.log then it display data but in case of flatlist data not display why

Answer (score 0):

some reasons

1)your text component in render item not bounded any view
try this
`<View> <Text>{item.name}</Text> </View>`

2. `keyExtractor={item=>item.key}` add this in flatlist in which key is string value which is unique in your data like id or something

this is my code which may be help you

```
const itembuilder=({item,index})=>

{

 return(

   <View
        style={{
        margin:10,borderRadius:20,shadowOpacity:0.5,
        shadowOffset:{height:-15,width:15},
        shadowColor:'#FFF8DC'
        ,justifyContent:'center',shadowRadius:25,elevation:15,
        height:200,
        marginBottom:20,
        backgroundColor:'white'}}>
        
       <Text>{item.name}</Text>

       </View>
        
    )
}
 <FlatList
    
    
    style={{height:500}}
    data={product}
    keyExtractor={item=>item.key}
    renderItem={itembuilder}
    >

    </FlatList>
```

Comment: i tried this ,but it not print list of data ,it print only single name

Answer (score 0):

```
   const itembuilder=({item,index})=>

{

  console.log(item)//will provide data comes in each array object
 return(

   <View
        style={{
        margin:10,borderRadius:20,shadowOpacity:0.5,
        shadowOffset:{height:-15,width:15},
        shadowColor:'#FFF8DC'
        ,justifyContent:'center',shadowRadius:25,elevation:15,
        height:200,
        marginBottom:20,
        backgroundColor:'white'}}>
        
       <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text>{item.email}</Text>//data inside each array object
         <Text>{item.phone}</Text>    
       </View>
        
    )
}
 <FlatList
    
    
    style={{height:500}}
    data={product}
    keyExtractor={item=>item.key}
    renderItem={itembuilder}
    >

    </FlatList>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more details as to what your code does, and why does it solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for fetching Donors

```
const fetchDonors = async () => { 
  const response = await firebase.firestore().collection('Donors').get(); 
  const data = response.docs.map(doc => doc.data());)
  setDonors(prev => [...prev,...data];
}
```